# Cannot max out hd partition size

Tags: partitioning

I am using Ubuntu server (no GUI installed at the moment). I am setting it up as a Time Machine backup. I have navigated all the steps, only to discover that the first (and only) partition on my second hard drive, which is 2TB, is showing up as only 356.9GB.

I have re-partitioned and re-formatted the drive more than once, and after I delete the old partition(s) and add the new one, I select partition #1, and then it asks for the first sector, which I have entered as 0 or 1, and the last sector, which I have entered as the default, highest number in the range available, 748516545. It always appears (on both Ubuntu and OSX), as only having 356.9GB.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make this partition larger than the highest number offered? Any suggestions would be welcome, along with step-by-step guidance, or links, where possible. I'm brand new to this.

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu! Hmm, the last sector `748516545` does indeed equate to 356.9GB. That means there might not be free space after that. What's the output of `sudo parted /dev/sdX unit GB print free` (`sdX` being the name of your drive)? You can [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/506941/edit) by clicking on the small `edit` link right underneath it.